# (C# application with oracle database) returning out parameters in stored procedures

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I am new to Oracle. I am receiving an exception when I am trying to get the values of the `out` parameters in the following procedure:

The procedure's job is to bring some information about a drug, given its ID, and store results in `out` parameters

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE RETREIVE_DRUG(
    drugId in "Drug"."DRUG_ID"%type,
    drugName OUT "Drug"."NAME"%type,
    prodDate OUT "Drug"."PRODUCTION_DATE"%type,
    expireDate OUT "Drug"."EXPIRATION_DATE"%type,
    price OUT "Drug"."PRICE"%type,
    description OUT "Drug"."DESCRIPTION"%type,
    quantity OUT "Drug"."QUANTITY"%type,
    buying OUT "Drug"."COST"%type,
    company OUT "Drug"."COMPANY"%type
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT "NAME", "PRODUCTION_DATE", "EXPIRATION_DATE", "PRICE", "DESCRIPTION", "QUANTITY", "COST", "COMPANY"
    INTO drugName, prodDate, expireDate, price, description, quantity, buying, company
    FROM "Drug"
    WHERE "Drug"."DRUG_ID" = drugId;
END RETREIVE_DRUG;
```

the c# code that invokes the procedure is as follows

```
public String[] Get_Drug(int id)
        {
            OpenConnection();

            OracleCommand oraCmd = new OracleCommand();
            oraCmd.Connection = con;
            oraCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            oraCmd.CommandText = "RETREIVE_DRUG";

            OracleParameter[] param = new OracleParameter[9];

            param[0] = new OracleParameter("DRUG_ID", OracleDbType.Decimal);
            param[0].Value = id;
            param[1] = new OracleParameter("NAME", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
            param[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            param[2] = new OracleParameter("PRODUCTION_DATE", OracleDbType.Date);
            param[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            param[3] = new OracleParameter("EXPIRATION_DATE", OracleDbType.Date);
            param[3].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            param[4] = new OracleParameter("PRICE", OracleDbType.Decimal);
            param[4].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            param[5] = new OracleParameter("DESCRIPTION", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
            param[5].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            param[6] = new OracleParameter("QUANTITY", OracleDbType.Decimal);
            param[6].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            param[7] = new OracleParameter("COST", OracleDbType.Decimal);
            param[7].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            param[8] = new OracleParameter("COMPANY", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
            param[8].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            oraCmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);

            oraCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            CloseConnection();  
            String[] ret = new String[8];

            ret[0] =oraCmd.Parameters["NAME"].Value.ToString();
            ret[1] =oraCmd.Parameters["PRODUCTION_DATE"].Value.ToString();
            ret[2] =oraCmd.Parameters["EXPIRATION_DATE"].Value.ToString();
            ret[3] =oraCmd.Parameters["PRICE"].Value.ToString();
            ret[4] =oraCmd.Parameters["DESCRIPTION"].Value.ToString();
            ret[5] =oraCmd.Parameters["QUANTITY"].Value.ToString();
            ret[6] =oraCmd.Parameters["COST"].Value.ToString();
            ret[7] =oraCmd.Parameters["COMPANY"].Value.ToString();

            return ret;
        }
```

But when I run the code, the following exception is shown up:

> PL\SQL: numeric or value error

Although I am sure about the names and the types. Please help. I have done a lot of effort in the problem without being able to solve it!

Comment: There is no further detail such as "character to number conversion error" / "number precision too large", or even a line number? Does calling the procedure in SQL Plus / SQL Developer / ... work? If you can't work it out by inspecting the code, you might want to (i) remove half of the parameters, (ii) check, whether the issue persists, and (iii) continue with narrowing down the set of parameters, which apparently holds the troublemaker.

Comment: thanks but the problem was I should've added a dataAdapter that's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I defined the size of `varchar` parameters (`drugName`, `description`, `company`) and changed parameter names exactly as they are in Oracle code, for instance, `buying` instead of `COST`. Finally added binding by name and below function worked fine:

```
public String[] Get_Drug(int id)
{
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();

    con.ConnectionString = "User Id=scott;Password=tiger;Data Source=XE";
    con.Open();

    OracleCommand oraCmd = new OracleCommand();
    oraCmd.Connection = con;
    oraCmd.BindByName = true;
    oraCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    oraCmd.CommandText = "RETREIVE_DRUG";

    OracleParameter[] param = new OracleParameter[9];

    param[0] = new OracleParameter("drugId", OracleDbType.Decimal);
    param[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    param[0].Value = id;
    param[1] = new OracleParameter("drugName", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
    param[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    param[1].Size = 30;
    param[2] = new OracleParameter("prodDate", OracleDbType.Date);
    param[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    param[3] = new OracleParameter("expireDate", OracleDbType.Date);
    param[3].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    param[4] = new OracleParameter("price", OracleDbType.Decimal);
    param[4].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    param[5] = new OracleParameter("description", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
    param[5].Size = 30;
    param[5].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    param[6] = new OracleParameter("quantity", OracleDbType.Decimal);
    param[6].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    param[7] = new OracleParameter("buying", OracleDbType.Decimal);
    param[7].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    param[8] = new OracleParameter("company", OracleDbType.Varchar2);
    param[8].Size = 30;
    param[8].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    oraCmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);

    oraCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

    String[] ret = new String[8];
    ret[0] = oraCmd.Parameters["drugName"].Value.ToString();
    ret[1] = oraCmd.Parameters["prodDate"].Value.ToString();
    ret[2] = oraCmd.Parameters["expireDate"].Value.ToString();
    ret[3] = oraCmd.Parameters["price"].Value.ToString();
    ret[4] = oraCmd.Parameters["description"].Value.ToString();
    ret[5] = oraCmd.Parameters["quantity"].Value.ToString();
    ret[6] = oraCmd.Parameters["buying"].Value.ToString();
    ret[7] = oraCmd.Parameters["company"].Value.ToString();
    return ret;
}
```

Probably second and third step is not key if you bind parameters by position, but defining by name is more readable. Here is the table structure and example data I used for test purposes:

```
create table "Drug" ("DRUG_ID" number, "NAME" varchar2(10), "PRODUCTION_DATE" date, 
  "EXPIRATION_DATE" date, "PRICE" number, "DESCRIPTION" varchar2(10), "QUANTITY" number, 
  "COST" number, "COMPANY" varchar2(10));
insert into "Drug" values (
  1, 'Name1', date '2015-01-18', date '2016-01-18', 100, 'Desc1', 900, 30, 'Comp1');
```

Comment: thanks but the problem was I should've added a dataAdapter that's all

Comment: and your suggest about the size is necessary too thanx